# Select specific columns using EF in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to get some specific column values using `Entity Framework` in MVC 5. But it's showing me error. Here is my code for controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var systemUsers = db.SystemUsers
                        .Include(s => s.SystemUser1)
                        .Select(s => new {
                                          s.FullName, 
                                          s.Email, 
                                          s.Image, 
                                          s.UpdateDate, 
                                          s.UpdatedBy, 
                                          s.Id
                                 });
    return View(systemUsers.ToList());
}
```

This is the error message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVC.Models.SystemUser]'.

Again when I'm unable to get single result with specific columns. By default controller method also returning unexpected foreign key data while trying to get using `ajax`. 
Here is the code for single result.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    SystemUser systemUser = db.SystemUsers.Find(id);
    return Json(systemUser);
}
```

[Here is the result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2qUb.png)

Comment: have you heard about view models? google it

Comment: The view requires a strongly typed view model but you are passing an anonymous type.

Comment: @Nkosi, Where to edit my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The view requires a strongly typed view model but you are passing an anonymous type

Update the select to return a strongly typed object collection.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var systemUsers = db.SystemUsers
                        .Include(s => s.SystemUser1)
                        .Select(s => new SystemUser { //<--HERE
                                         FullName = s.FullName, 
                                         Email = s.Email, 
                                         Image = s.Image, 
                                         UpdateDate = s.UpdateDate, 
                                         UpdatedBy = s.UpdatedBy, 
                                         Id = s.Id
                                 });
    return View(systemUsers.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems to be that your View is expecting an `IEnumerable<SystemUser>` as **View Model**, but instead you are supplying an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instance. That's why the compiler fails. There are several ways to solve this:

1- Make your *View* take in a `dynamic` model: You won't have to worry about the *type* of the actual instance passed in, however you won't have the niceties of *auto-completion* or *intellisense*.

2- Do not project (`.Select`) your collection and pass the original `SystemUser` list to the *View*

3- Create a View Model and make a list of such view models and pass that on to the view:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var systemUsers = db.SystemUsers
                    .Include(s => s.SystemUser1)
                    .Select(s => new SystemUserViewModel 
                            {
                                FullName = s.FullName, 
                                Email = s.Email, 
                                Image = s.Image, 
                                UpdateDate = s.UpdateDate, 
                                UpdatedBy = s.UpdatedBy, 
                                Id = s.Id
                             });
    return View(systemUsers)
}
```

IMHO the 3rd is the best one. You should of course use the one that suits your needs best. Hope this help

Comment: His code is bad enough that it contains queries in the controller and now you are suggesting to him to send the query `SystemUsers` all the way to the view? How is that a good suggestion? I would remove your 2nd suggestion.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, lol, I tried to provide different suggestions and trying to convey how `Views` and `ViewModels` work without being too opinionated about it. That's why I recommended the 3rd solution

Comment: But that is not a good suggestion so it should not be suggested.